# How to host a nodejs app on ECS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Iam looking to host a nodejs app on ECS. On local dev i use ngrok to expose port 3000 and it seems to work well. Now i would like to host it. Is dockerizing mandatory? What would be the steps to host it on amazon ecs if the app is dockerized?

I would also like to know if hosting on ecs is possible without dockerizing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you if you want to go this way to start an EB Instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html

And you can deploy your application using CodeShip or use the traditional way in EB where you upload and deploy the code ( I suggest you use CodeShip ).

Another way to do it, and it might end it up being free is Heroku, it's an amazing and easy cloud service where you can deploy your application and build a continuous integration with GitHub, it takes care of everything to you. 
This is the walkthrough for Node.Js apps:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Dockerizing is not mandatory at all, you can do it if you like, the roadmap to deploy the app won't change.